# My last column isn't getting populated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to use a non-xml format file to bulk import a null delimited file into sql. I've added a column to the staging table in question, and updated the format file to reflect this. Everything seems to be inserting fine, except this last column. The column I added is

```
Comments (nvarchar(256), null)
```

The format file looks like this:

```
11.0
8
1   SQLNCHAR    0   4   "\0\0"  1   ClaimCheckSetId ""
2   SQLNCHAR    0   4   "\0\0"  2   BatchValidationId   ""
3   SQLNCHAR    0   4   "\0\0"  3   SourceCommunicationId   ""
4   SQLNCHAR    0   4   "\0\0"  4   TargetCommunicationId   ""
5   SQLNCHAR    0   1800    "\0\0"  5   TargetExternalCommunicationId   ""
6   SQLNCHAR    0   8   "\0\0"  6   TargetSentDateTime  ""
7   SQLNCHAR    0   2000    "\0\0"  7   TargetSubject   ""
8   SQLNCHAR    0   256 "\r\0\n\0"  8   Comments ""
```

The SQL looks like this:

```
DECLARE @filepath NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'C:\{file to import}_512fc21d-dbc9-4975-8169-2ca383ac2bdf.txt';
DECLARE @formatpath NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'C:\{format file}.txt';
DECLARE @bulkinsert NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET
        @bulkinsert = 
        N'BULK INSERT 
            [The Table]
            FROM ''' +
            @filepath + N''' 
            WITH 
            (
                FORMATFILE = ''' +
                @formatpath + N''',
                DATAFILETYPE = ''WIDECHAR'',
                FIRSTROW = 1
            )';

    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
    EXEC sp_executesql @Bulkinsert;
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
```

I'm getting no errors, and it is returning a number of rows affected. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about SQL to diagnose this problem. A few hours of googling have not helped either. I hope one of you kind guys or gals can set me back on the straight and narrow.

Update: I edited the \r\0\n\0 to \r\n and am now getting an error!

```
OLE DB provider 'BULK' for linked server '(null)' returned invalid data for column '[BULK].InsertedDateTime'.
```

Comment: What does your C:\{format file}.txt look like?

Comment: Hmm I would bet that your last field separator should be `\r\n`.

Comment: @KamranFarzami, the format file is included in the post.

Comment: @TT. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the input file in an editor that shows special symbols. Personally I use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (free) for that (`View > Show Symbol > Show All Characters`), but any decent editor will do.

That way the row terminator (ie the last field terminator) should be clearly visible. In Notepad++ the `\0` will be visible as `NUL`, `\r` AS `CR` and `\n` AS `LF`.

So with your settings as you currently have, you should be seeing `CR NUL LF NUL`. If you don't then change the last field terminator to what you see in the editor you are using.

Comment: So, it's CR LF. The nulls aren't there. I have used both the string literal "\r\n" and Environment.NewLine (c#).

Comment: This did it. There were a couple of problems in the format file. I thought I was looking at all characters, because I could see the nulls in notepad++. Thanks for having me dig a little deeper! I'll remember it!

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information I have, can you please change the following

```
8   SQLNCHAR    0   256 "\r\0\n\0"  8   Comments ""
```

to

```
8   SQLNCHAR    0   256 "\r\n"  8   Comments ""
```

or

```
8   SQLNCHAR    0   256 "\0\0"  8   Comments ""
```

It seems the last one should wrap to new line.

Comment: The carriage return is supposed to be there, I think. All the other format files I'm looking at work this way. Is there some more info I can provide you with?

Comment: As I have pointed above, `\r\n` looks like the most suitable format, unless the source file has a completely different definition.